# Angular2 component with 2 children routers - don't know how to navigate from one child to the other

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have parent component which defines a Router which points to 2 child components which themselves have a Router each, something like

**Parent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import {Child1WithRouterComponent} from './childWithRouter1.component';
import {Child2WithRouterComponent} from './childWithRouter2.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'mex-app',
  template: `
        <h2>MEAN2 Examples</h2>
        <div style="width: 30%;float:left">
          <button type="button" style="width: 100%"
                  (click)="child1()">Child 1</button>
          <button type="button" style="width: 100%"
                  (click)="child2()">Child 2</button>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 70%;float:left">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/child1/...', name: 'Child1', component: Child1WithRouterComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path: '/child2/...', name: 'Child2', component: Child2WithRouterComponent}
])
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  child1() {
    this.router.navigate['Child1']
  }
  child2() {
    this.router.navigate['Child2']
  }
}
```

**Child1**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import {GrandChild1Component} from './grandChild1.component';
import {GrandChild2Component} from './grandChild2.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'mex-child1',
  template: `
        <h3>Child with router</h3>
        <button type="button" 
                  (click)="goToGrandChild1()">GO TO GRAND CHILD1</button>
        <button type="button" 
                  (click)="goToGrandChild2()">GO TO GRAND CHILD2</button>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],

})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/grand-child-1', name: 'GrandChild1', component: GrandChild1Component},
  {path: '/grand-child-2', name: 'GrandChild2', component: GrandChild2Component}
])
export class Child1WithRouterComponent { 
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  goToGrandChild1() {
    this.router.navigate(['GrandChild1'])
  }
  goToGrandChild2() {
    this.router.navigate(['GrandChild2'])
  }
}
```

**Child2** is same as **Child1** apart its RouteConfig which is

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/grand-child-3', name: 'GrandChild3', component: GrandChild3Component},
  {path: '/grand-child-4', name: 'GrandChild4', component: GrandChild4Component}
])
```

Parent should be able to programmatically navigate from Child1 to Child2 and viceversa executing `this.router.navigate['Child1']` or `this.router.navigate['Child2']`.

Unfortunately when I try to navigate from Child1 (the default) to Child2 nothing happens.

Thanks in advance for any support

Comment: Have you tried setting `useAsDefault: true` on one of the `GrandChildX` routes?

Comment: No, I choose the GrandChildX programmatically from ChildY. I have the specified the default Child in the Parent RouteConfig and in fact I land correctly on the default child; once on the default Child I can navigate to its grandchildren; but when I click a button on the Parent component to navigate to the other Child nothing happens.

Comment: I don't see how you choose it programmatically. When you navigate to `['ChildX']` then I think there needs a default grand-child or you specify one in the parameter you pass to `navigate` like `_this.router.navigate(['Child1', 'GrandChild1'])`. Can you try if one of these fixes your issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to ['ChildX'] then I think there needs a default grand-child or you specify one in the parameter you pass to navigate like

```
_this.router.navigate(['Child1', 'GrandChild1'])
```